# Why is the binding icon not visible in blend?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, expression-blend

Why is the binding icon (a small gray icon) not visible in blend for some properties even though they are DependencyProperties? For eg. I dragged a button on my page and dragged a textbox. I want to bind button's content property to textbox's text property. But i can't find the Binding icon in Blend. I know if i type the binding syntax in code it will work just fine. But why is that icon missing?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Rathod: I tried reproducing this, but for me, the "Advanced Options" -> "Data Binding" is there. I'm using Blend 4, what version are you using?

Comment: @Meleak :- I was silly. Infact this is bug of Expression Blend 4. When you decrease the size of Properties window. The Advanced option button gets hidden. Further no scrollbar appears at the bottom which made me feel that my icon is missing. When you said it is visible. Thanks to you. I had this doubt since too many days. You may post your comment as answer. I will tick it. Thanks again :)

Comment: Rathod: Sure thing :) This is something I've never noticed myself but I can see how this can easily happen. Good thing to know about!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried reproducing this, but for me, the "Advanced Options" -> "Data Binding" is there. I'm using Blend 4, what version are you using?